# Emailing multiple ranges as attachments from VB code

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, range, attachment

I have used some standard code from the internet to use a button to create an email in Outlook with an attachment that is a range in the worksheet where the button is pressed.The code works beautifully. ***How can I extend the code to attach two or more ranges?*** In the code below, I already started initializing a second Source and Dest, but then lost confidence regarding how this should be applied.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Source2 As Range
    Dim Dest As Workbook
    Dim Dest2 As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim AutoPrint As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set Source = Nothing
    Set Source2 = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Source = Range("A1:M47").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set Source2 = Range("AB1:AN47").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Source Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected, please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Set Dest2 = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Source.Copy
    With Dest.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
    
    If Range("AC6") <> "" Then
    Source2.Copy
    With Dest2.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
    End If

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Selection of " & wb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2016
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    AutoPrint = Range("Y6").Value

    With Dest
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = Range("S6").Value
            .CC = Range("S3").Value
            If Range("T3").Value = "Enter bcc addresses manually here" Then
            .bcc = ""
            Else
            .bcc = Range("T3").Value
            End If
            .Subject = Range("V6").Value
            .Body = Range("U6").Value
            .Attachments.Add Dest.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            If AutoPrint = "Yes" Then
            .Send   'or use .Display
            Else
            .Display
            End If
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The "best" approach here would be to extract the code which creates a new file from the supplied range into a separate method, so you can call it more than one time if needed.  If you make that method a Function, it can return the full path to the temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from my comment above:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim OutApp As Object, AutoPrint
    Dim colAttachments As New Collection, fPath As String, ws As Worksheet, tm, p
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    tm = Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
    
    'first attachment
    fPath = CreateAttachment(ws.Range("A1:M47"), _
                            "Selection1 of " & ws.Parent.Name & " " & tm)
    If Len(fPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'exit if there was a problem
    colAttachments.Add fPath
    
    If ws.Range("AC6") <> "" Then    'second attachment? Note the filename needs to be distinct...
        fPath = CreateAttachment(ws.Range("AB1:AN47"), _
                                 "Selection2 of " & ws.Parent.Name & " " & tm)
        If Len(fPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'exit if there was a problem
        colAttachments.Add fPath
    End If
        
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    AutoPrint = ws.Range("Y6").Value
    With OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        .to = ws.Range("S6").Value
        .CC = ws.Range("S3").Value
        If ws.Range("T3").Value = "Enter bcc addresses manually here" Then
            .bcc = ""
        Else
            .bcc = ws.Range("T3").Value
        End If
        .Subject = ws.Range("V6").Value
        .Body = ws.Range("U6").Value
        For Each p In colAttachments  'add each attachment from the collection
            .Attachments.Add p
            Kill p
        Next p
        If AutoPrint = "Yes" Then
            .Send
        Else
            .Display
        End If
    End With
      
End Sub

'create a file from the visible cells in `rng`
'  and return the path to the file
Function CreateAttachment(rng As Range, fName As String) As String
    Dim rngVis As Range, ws As Worksheet, ext, fPath As String
    'try to get a range with only visible cells
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngVis = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rngVis Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
        "Please correct and try again.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set ws = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Sheets(1)
        rngVis.Copy
        With ws.Cells(1)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths '8
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            .Select
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ext = IIf(Val(Application.Version) < 12, ".xls", ".xlsx")
        fPath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & fName & ext
        ws.Parent.SaveAs fPath
        ws.Parent.Close False
        CreateAttachment = fPath
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing so much detail in your answer. Really basic question: I have tried to attach this code to an ActiveX button, and the code seems to be falling over at the start of the function. Am I right in thinking that the button only recognizes the Private Sub/End Sub code, and that somehow I need to combine the Function into this? At this point I can't tell whether the code is working or not...

Comment: The function is called from `CommandButton2_Click` so your button only needs to call that Sub

Comment: FYI "falling over" is not very descriptive - if you're having problems with the code it always helps to describe exactly what's happening.  If you get an error, what's the error message and which line is highlighted if you click "Debug"?

Comment: If I run the Debug, the temporary file names get created fine, and then I get a Run-time error '-2147417856 (80010100)': Automation error System call failed. I don't see a row highlighted when I get this error. Is this in some way connected with the fact that there are three separate command buttons defined?

Comment: My original code that only creates one attachment is on CommandButton2, and I put your code (with a few very simple changes) on CommandButton3.

Comment: Try commenting out the `Kill` line and see if that changes anything.  If not I can test a little later.

Comment: Getting the same error... Thanks in advance for looking at this!

Comment: Is your ActiveX button on a worksheet?

Comment: Yes, it's on the same worksheet as the ranges I want to attach

Comment: On testing, this is working fine for me.  I did miss a couple of variable declarations in `CommandButton2_Click` (added above).  You'll need to step through with F8 and figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Debugging your code - https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code

Comment: The F8 steps work through all the code nicely, up to this line:     Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application"). Then I get the run time error

Comment: Is Outlook already running when you run the code?

Comment: Code works beautifully - problem was with my copy of Outlook, which needed re-installing for some reason! Thank you so much, for answering this question really thoroughly and quickly, and providing me with actionable feedback.

Comment: Good to hear it's working out for you.